# How to connect different controllers to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on some project and I have create and edit pages for some entity. The html page for both of them is the same but the controllers are different, I want to create a directive that will have the html and I will "inject" the relevant controller(create or edit) to the directive.

I'm using the directives as classes in ES6, I have tired to use the bindToContoller and the controller field to "inject" my controller without success.

```
import EntityCreateController from '../../create/controller';
class FormDirective
{
    constructor() {
        this.template = require('./directive.html');

        this.restrict = 'E';

        this.replace = true;

        this.controllerAs = 'ctrl';

        this.bindToController = true;

        this.controller = EntityCreateController;

        this.transclue = true;

        this.scope = {
            record: '=',
            ngModel: '=',
        };

        this.link = (scope, elem, attrs, controller) => {
            controller.EntityCreate = scope.form
        };
    }
}

export default EntityCreateController;
```

I have problems with the form attachment to the controller in the link function. And some other things dont work as I expected.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour ? and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Be a lot more specific. *"dont work as I expected"* is a virtually meaningless technical problem statement especially when we can't run the code ourselves to witness issues

Comment: As I have said: I'm having a problem in the form attachment. The binding happens in delay. In addition, I want to know if that the best practice to do so. In the future instead of the create controller I will bind the edit controller.